# Edit category output

Tags: php, categories

I am using the following to display all the categories from my custom post type. How can I edit it so instead of having the output of the categories in `<ul><li>` elements it has `<a href ....` instead? I need to edit the output of `wp_list_categories( $args );`

```
<?php $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('video');

if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
{
     foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
     {
         $args = array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'show_count' => 0,
              'pad_counts' => 0,
              'hierarchical' => 1,
              'taxonomy' => $tax,
              'title_li' => ''
            );
            echo '<span class="tags-button" style="list-style:none; float:left;">';
         wp_list_categories( $args );
         echo '</span>';
     }
} ?>
```

Comment: On the $args, add another parameter - `'style' => 'simple'`

Comment: @Shazzad That worked but how would i remove the BR it generates after each category?

Comment: Answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `style` parameter to define the type of list. And to remove `<br />` tags from the list, set parameter `'echo' => 0` and str_replace to remove `<br />` tag from the output.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'show_count' => 0,
    'pad_counts' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => $tax,
    'title_li' => '',
    'echo' => 0,
    'style' => 'simple'
);

echo '<span class="tags-button" style="list-style:none; float:left;">';
    echo str_replace( '<br />', '', wp_list_categories( $args ) );
echo '</span>';
```